# Type casting a string variable to a map in Java

Tags: java, string, dictionary, casting

I have a string variable. I need to typecast this variable to a map variable. For instance:

```
 String stringVariable = "apple"
 // type cast this to map (Map<string,string>) stringVariable
```

I would like to use `apple` as a map and not as a string. Is it possible?

Comment: `Map` implements a key/value pair mechanism. You can't directly type cast a `String` to a `Map`. Declare a `Map` and use the `mapObj.put("key", "value")` method to store strings into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. You need to *parse* the string somehow.

That said, I have no idea how to parse `"apple"` as a map. A string such as `"favorite -> apple"` would be more understandable.

Comment: parsing in the sense ... How does that help

Comment: A `Map<String, String>` *maps* strings (keys) to other strings (values). What *mappings* would you like for your `"apple"` map?

Comment: no my requirement is I will get this apple name from outside ..I would like to type cast it to map ans use it .. If I get "mango" from outside .. I need to type cast that to map and use the same

Comment: A `String` is a `String` and not a `Map`. Bottom line is that you *can't* cast it. Tell the guy that wrote the requirement that it doesn't make sense unless he tells you *how* the string should be interpreted as a map. ("Just casting it" simply won't do as an explanation.)

Comment: Ya I know the fact.. But was just curious to know is there any possiblity .. Thanks for your reply guys

Answer (score 0):

You definitely cannot cannot "apple" to a Map because Map is a Collection which deals with Key-Value Pairs and Apple is just a value.

You can cast something like "apple" = "red" or "apple":"red" to a Map

Or worst case you can try casting "apple" to a Map which will look something like
["apple":null] which does not make any sense though.